# Undesired shortcut shown in the Recent Opened Programs in start menu on Windows 7

Tags: shell, winapi, installation

My software has two .EXE files : A.exe and B.exe. After installed on Window 7, the shortcut to A.exe is always shown in the start menu. (I don't know if 'Start menu' is the correct name or not, what I mean is the area above 'All Programs').

The menu in my computer looks like:

---

```
Getting Started
Windows Media Center
Calculator
Sticky Notes
Snipping Tool
Paint
A                   <-- My program, and I want 'B' to be shown here
All programs
```

---

How can I change my installer to make B.exe shown instead of A.exe?

Best regards,
Zach

---

**EDIT**

I found a similar post on this problem. The URL is

http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/779545E28688F5CD862576430042680E?OpenDocument

except that in the article the user is using NI installer.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to fix this programmatically? Or just to fix the display in the start menu on your computer? If it's the former, please provide more details, if it's the latter, the question should be closed.

Comment: We would need to know how your installer works. What's the technology?

Comment: @incrediman, I'm looking for a way to fix this programmatically. I think my question is detailed enough. Two EXE files in my install package, but Windows chooses A.exe displaying in the start menu. What I want is B.exe is showing instead. I'm not sure I'm clear enough. 

I use MSI to create the installer.

Comment: It chooses whichever executable the user runs. If two shortcuts to the same executable exist, it does some heuristics to guess thr best one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is answer from Microsoft:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127439(v=vs.85).aspx

or here (how to do it from msi)
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2009/09/02/windows-7-taskbar-support-with-the-msishortcutproperty-table.aspx?Redirected=true